# Integrate Redmine with PHPStorm

Tags: redmine, phpstorm

I recently started using PHPStorm and wonder if there is any way to integrate full issue / bug / time tracking in Redmine with PHPStorm?

Answer (score 0):

To enable integration with an issue tracking system

> Access the Servers dialog box. Do one of the following:
>   Open the Project Settings. Below the Tasks node, click Servers.
>   In the Open Task dialog box, click settings.
>   On the main menu, choose Tools | Tasks&Contexts | Configure Servers
>   In the Servers dialog box, specify the following:
>   The URL address of your issue tracking server.
>   Your account credentials on the server in question. These credentials will be different for the different issue tracking systems.
>   Specify whether you want to access the server via proxy and specify the proxy settings.
>   To allow access to the specified server for other members of your team, select the Share URL check box.
>   To check whether the specified settings ensure successful connection to the server, click the Test button.
>
> Configure synchronization between PhpStorm and your issue tracking system. To do so, open the Project Settings, and click Tasks. In the Tasks page, configure interaction between PhpStorm and your tracker. Do one of the following:
>
> To have PhpStorm synchronize with the issue tracking system in the background on a regular basis, select the Enable issue cache check box and specify the synchronization frequency and the cache size.

Taken from here: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/enabling-integration-with-an-issue-tracking-system.html

Another one here: http://saiteneffekt.de/2012/04/integrate-redmine-into-phpstormintellij-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: If you copy pasted some text, please wrap it in block quotes using the Ctrl-Q keyboard shortcut or the appropriate editor button.

Comment: thanx for the warn